# How can I remove ugly white spaces created by justify-aligned text in an H3 CSS element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

White spaces does not disappear, I tried a lot in CSS and nothing seems to work. It is an H3 element to display the title of the news.

I tried the following code:

```css
.news-titles {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: left;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-justify: distribute;
  word-spacing: -2px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="news-titles">
  <a href="single.html">
    Fanatical regime is killing anyone who opposes its islamic ideals
  </a>
</h3>
```

I am attaching an image of the result and as you can see, the hyphens are working and the text is actually expanding with the justify-alignment but it is also creating some ugly white spaces and I cannot get them to disappear.

Any idea why? Is there any better/other method using Jquery/Javascript?

Here is how it looks

[image: Click to see image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML on which your CSS is applied. You should be able to use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a [mre] right here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I edited and added the html

Comment: You may want to read that link to [mre] again, and perhaps add some CSS so that it replicates the issue more closely.

Comment: The ugly whitespace is a side effect of justifying text, you may prefer not justifying text but allowing word wrapping to break words

Comment: Unfortunately the `text-justify` is not widely supported -> https://caniuse.com/css-text-justify

Comment: Harrison, is the any other way? maybe with Jquery or javascript ? using word break just break the words without hyphens :(

Comment: You have a couple of options here, you could manually put more hythens in.  If you wanted inter char/word justification with full control, you could render the text as an SVG.   Another option, remove the justification / or smaller font, justifying no matter what method you use will will have issues with large fonts as it's not obvious what the rendering engine it to do with the extra white-space on wrapping.   Looking at your image, I'm just wondering if things would just look good if your right aligned.

Comment: I tried aligning it to right but it looks even uglier because the main language is not arabic :( and because these titles are dynamic news it is never the same text but it changes constantly

Comment: Aligning text to the right is not just an arabic thing, had right alignment headers and stuff in the UK for as long as can remember.   But yeah, if you think it's ugly then as a web designer, that's your call.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose `text-align: justify;`, there will be gaps automatically, since words often have different numbers of characters.

That's why "justification" is primarily something for the "print area" and not for the internet. Because in the area of ​​responsive design it becomes even more difficult.

Here you can find some examples & information, how text-align works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align?retiredLocale=en

And here you can find some information about `text-justify`, but like the others say, it's not well-supported yet:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify

If you still want to use `text-align: justify;` and you want no big spaces, you can try `word-break: break-all;` but that will destroy the classic reading flow for the users (not recommended).

Comment: Is there any other method to do this in Jquery or javascript? I mean we are in year 2023 and still no solution for this in any possible way?

Comment: From a usability point of view, it would be better to choose text-align left or right (depending on your country). text-align: justify don't read well.